# $f''(x)\ge m>0$, show that $ |\int_0^{+\infty}\exp(if(t))\mathrm{d}t | \le 8/\sqrt{m}$

Tags: integration, complex-integration, integral-inequality

How can this inequality be proven? I thought of writing $e^{if(t)}$ as $ \frac{1}{f'(t)} \cdot f'(t) e^{if(t)}$ to integrate by parts but I can't finish.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This inequality seems to be a consequence of the [Van der Corput lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Van_der_Corput_lemma_(harmonic_analysis)), but the constants given by this lemma give $\frac{10}{\sqrt{m}}$ instead of $\frac{8}{\sqrt{m}}$. To get this better inequality, we shall adapt the proof of Van Der Corput lemma.

> Step 1 : Let $a<b$, $f:[a,b]\to\mathbb{R}$ be continuously differentiable with $f''\ge 0$ such that $|f'| \ge \lambda>0$, then 
>   $$ \left|\int_a^b e^{if}\right| \le \dfrac{3}{\lambda}$$

Proof :
Because $|f'|>0$ we can write :
$$ \int_a^b e^{if} = \int_a^b \dfrac{1}{if'(t)}\cdot if'(t)e^{if(t)}\mathrm{d}t= \dfrac{e^{if(b)}}{if'(b)} - \dfrac{e^{if(a)}}{if'(a)} + \int_a^b \dfrac{f''(t)}{f'(t)^2}e^{if(t)}\mathrm{d}t$$
Taking module on both sides, and applying triangular inequality we get :
$$ \left|\int_a^b e^{if}\right|\le \frac{1}{|f'(b)|} + \frac{1}{|f'(a)|} + \int_a^b \dfrac{f''(t)}{f'(t)^2}\mathrm{d}t$$
$$ \le \dfrac{2}{\lambda} + \dfrac{1}{f'(a)} - \dfrac{1}{f'(b)}\le \dfrac{3}{\lambda}$$
Which concludes the proof of step 1.

> Step 2 :Let $a < b$, $f:[a,b]\to\mathbb{R}$ be twice continuously differentiable such that $f''\ge m >0$, And $f'(t)\neq 0$ for all $t$ then 
>   $$ \left|\int_a^b e^{if}\right| \le \dfrac{4}{\sqrt{m}}$$

Proof :
Because $f'(t)\neq 0$ for all $t$, and that $f'$ is continous, then $f'$ is of constant sign on $[a,b]$.
Suppose first that $f'>0$. Let $\alpha >0$, with $\alpha < b-a$, then if $x\in [a+\alpha, b]$:
$$ f'(x) = f'(a) + \int_a^{x} f''(t)\mathrm{d}t\ge \alpha m$$
Then, by applying step 1 we get :
$$ \left|\int_a^b e^{if(t)}\mathrm{d}t\right| \le \int_a^{a+\alpha} 1 + \dfrac{3}{\alpha m} = \alpha + \dfrac{3}{\alpha\cdot m}$$
If $\alpha \ge b-a$, then the inequality still holds as the integral is less than $b-a$.

Taking $\alpha = \frac{1}{\sqrt{m}}$ we get :
$$ \left| \int_a^b e^{if}\right| \le \dfrac{4}{\sqrt{m}}$$
In the case where $f'<0$, the proof is the same but instead, we split the integral between $a$ and $b-\alpha$, and $b-\alpha, b$.
So the proof of step 2 is done.

> Step 3 : let $f:\mathbb{R}_+\to\mathbb{R}$ be twice continuously differentiable such that $f''\ge m>0$, then
>    $$ \left|\int_0^{\infty} e^{if(t)}\mathrm{d}t\right|\le \dfrac{8}{\sqrt{m}}$$

Proof : first, it is needed to show that the integral converges. For $x$ big enough, $f'\ge 1$, so we can integrate by parts like in step 1 and get a converging integral.
Now, one of two things can happen :
Either $f'(t)\neq 0$ for all $t$, then we can apply step 2 directly by taking $a=0$ and letting $b\to+\infty$ to get the even better inequality 
$$ \left|\int_0^{\infty} e^{if(t)}\mathrm{d}t \right| \le \dfrac{4}{\sqrt{m}}$$

Or, their exists $c\ge 0$ such that $f'(c)=0$, because $f''>0$, this $c$ is unique, if $c=0$, we can just let $a\to 0$ and $b\to+\infty$ in step 2 to get the same inequality as before. Otherwise, let $\varepsilon > 0$, then :
$$ \left| \int_0^{\infty} e^{if}\right| \le \left| \int_0^{c-\varepsilon} e^{if}\right| + 2\varepsilon + \left|\int_{c+\varepsilon}^{+\infty} e^{if}\right| \le \dfrac{8}{\sqrt{m}} + 2\varepsilon$$
Letting $\varepsilon \to 0$, we get what we want.